# Do the 3 red stars on Washington DC's flag represent 3 city states?

Tags: united-states

There seems to be an [explanation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/26566406/The-3-City-States) of the meaning of the stars on Washington DC's flag.

> There are three cities (city-states) across this planet that share striking similarities and play a crucial role in the global governmental system we have long been living under. The three city-states (along with the role they serve) is as follows:
>
> **City of London** (finance)
> **Washington DC** (military)
> **Vatican City** (religion)
>
> The aforementioned city-states listed above are sovereign, corporate entities not connected to the nations they appear to be part of. In other words, the City of London (that is the square mile within Greater London) is not technically part of Greater London or England, just as Vatican City is not part of Rome or Italy. Likewise, Washington DC is not part of the United States that it controls.
>
> These sovereign, corporate entities have their own laws and their own identities. They also have their own flags. Seen below is the flag of Washington DC. Note the three stars, representing the trinity of these three city-states, also known as the Empire of the City. (There is also high esoteric significance to the number 3.)

Within the U.S., the flag is frequently displayed, not only on public buildings, but on private residences. What is the true meaning of Washington DC's flag?

Comment: Other corrections to false claims: the City of London is a part of both Greater London and of England.  DC is not a state, but it is definitely a part of the United States.  Neither the City of London nor Washington D.C. is a sovereign entity.

Answer (score 55):

**No**

The flag of Washington, DC

[image: Flag of DC]<sub>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Washington,_D.C..svg)</sub>

Is based on the [coat of arms of George Washington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_George_Washington)

[image: coat of arms of george washington]<sub>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:COA_George_Washington.svg)</sub>

which also makes an appearance, along with George Washington's bust on the [Purple Heart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_Heart)

[image: purple heart]<sub>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Purpleheart.jpg)</sub>

So the the design of DC's flag is clearly taken from its namesake, George Washington.

The flag was designed by Charles A.R. Dunn who wrote [The Origins of the District of Columbia Flag](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40067187) about his flag design. He was employed painting US state flags, which made him notice that many of them lacked a good design and that there was no flag for Washington, DC. He was inspired by the flag of Maryland, which is the coat of arms of Lord Baltimore.

The Washington coat of arms has been around for a while before the United States, it even appears on a stained glass window in the [Selby Abbey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selby_Abbey)

[image: washington coat of arms on stained glass]<sub>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Washington_coat_of_arms.jpg)</sub>

Comment: Which transfers the question to: What do the three stars in this coat of arms stand for?

Comment: @GEdgar it seems that the answer to that question [has not come down to us from the 13th or 14th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_the_Washington_family).

Comment: @GEdgar that's a great question for the History site. While there is no mention as to the meaning on Wikipedia, you might get some information based on general heraldic knowledge.

Comment: @GEdgar In coats of arms, three is by far the most frequent number for small figures like stars.  Notice the aspect ratio of the space above the bars.